# R: extract data from one column based on string detected in another

Tags: r, string

I have a large dataset I wish to summarize.
The data are health records in which each individual has had many organs/tissues examined, and diagnoses are entered in narrative form.  I have a few key diagnosis terms I want to find, and then I want to know what organs were associated with the diagnosis.

example 
(all entries converted to character strings)

dataframe1

```
Organ          Diagnosis
lungs          interstitial pneumonia
liver          hepatic congestion ; diffuse
cerebrum       traumatic disruption and hemorrhage       
adrenal gland  focal hemorrhage
```

dataframe2

```
Keywords
congestion
hemorrhage
trauma
pneumonia
```

I want to search `dataframe1$Diagnosis` for strings that match `dataframe2$Keywords`, 
and for each match, return the organ entered in the corresponding row of `dataframe1$Organ`.

## data structures

```
dataframe1 <- structure(list(Organ = c("lungs", "liver", "cerebrum", "adrenal gland"
), Diagnosis = c("interstitial pneumonia", "hepatic congestion ; diffuse", 
"traumatic disruption and hemorrhage", "focal hemorrhage")), .Names = c("Organ", 
"Diagnosis"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

dataframe2 <- data.frame(Keywords=c("congestion","hemorrhage","trauma","pneumonia"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: dataframe1$Organ<-c(lungs, liver, cerebrum, adrenal gland) 
dataframe1$Diagnosis<-c( interstitial pneumonia, hepatic congestion, traumatic disruption and hemorrhage, focal hemorrhage)
dataframe2$Keywords<-c(congestion, hemorrhage, trauma, pneumonia)

Comment: sorry formatting horribly!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grep`

```
sapply(dataframe2$Keywords, function(x) 
       toString(trimws(dataframe1[,1][grep(x, dataframe1[,2])])))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's probably valuable to return a stacked list of what matches what, as in:

```
stack(
  sapply(dataframe2$Keywords, 
         function(x) dataframe1$Organ[grepl(x, dataframe1$Diagnosis)])
)

#         values        ind
#1         liver congestion
#2      cerebrum hemorrhage
#3 adrenal gland hemorrhage
#4      cerebrum     trauma
#5         lungs  pneumonia
```